# Definition about convergence of a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology, vector-analysis

I'm on a Vector Analysis class and was given a problem on the convergence/divergence of sequences on $\mathbb{R}^n$. The definition that we're using states that:

A sequence $x_n$ $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ converges to $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ if for every $\color{red}{\text{neighborhood }} U$ for point $a$ there exists $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k \in U$ for every $k \geqslant k_0.$

I'm a bit confused about the definition here. By neighbourhood do they mean something like the epsilon-neighborhood that's more related to topology than vector analysis?

Also the notation was described as $$\lim_{k\to\infty} ||x_k-a||=0$$

I guess the $ ||x_k-a||$ here is not an absolute value, but the Euclidean norm?

Comment: Analysis and calculus do use some topological terms and tools.

Comment: Yes.  A neighborhood of a point $a$ of radius $r$ is precisely the set of points $x$ such that $\|x-a\|<r$.  Now... what specifically $\|~~\|$ is depends on context.  It is common for it to be the euclidean norm, but it could have been something else as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz just updated the question about this. Thanks I guess it's the euclidean norm.

Comment: Again... it could have been any norm.  It is *common* for it to be the euclidean norm but it does not have to be.  The more complete sentence would have been "$x$ converges to $a$ *with respect to the ____ norm* yada yada."  It could just as well have been an $\ell_p$ norm for some $p\neq 2$.

Comment: I see. Though somewhat confusing as why would this definition use the concept of neighborhood. Wouldn't that then describe a ball and I'm not sure how the idea of a ball would relate to the idea of determining if a sequence is convergent(?). I'm familiar with the regular $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ from Analysis 1, but this seems quite different.

Comment: @Daniel An interval is just a one-dimensional ball.  There's really no difference.

Comment: I cannot imagine that in your class you have not been given the definition of a neighborhood and of $\lVert - \rVert$.